# Mongodb, count all objects in a field which is repeated in a collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a MongoDB collection called `tag` which contains 3 objects. These objects contain `_id`, `main`, `name`, etc. fields like the following:

```
{
    "_id": "2ho8XgtfRvXpkg9g6",
    "main": "category",
    "name": ["elec", "toys", "flowers"]
}
```

I want to count all the items in `name` array (there are 3 here, 4 there, 5 in last).

How can I use the following query to count all items, in all array `name`, in all 3 tag collection?

```
Tags.find().count()
```

Answer (score 0):

This aggregation query will give you the total sum of the name array:

```
db.tag.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$name"},
    {"$group": {"_id": "$_id", "sum": { "$sum": 1}}},
    {"$group": {"_id": null, "total_sum": {"$sum": "$sum"}}}

])
```